# boost::static_visitor failed to specialise function template with multiple different possible types

Tags: c++, templates, boost, operator-overloading, sfinae

I'm trying to create a visitor function that will add together values of my `boost::variant`. I am using templates for the case where the types are different for example `int + float`

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float> Values;

struct Add : public boost::static_visitor<Values> {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto operator() (T a, U b) const -> decltype(a + b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

This compiles and works fine

```
std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(Add{}, (Values)2, (Values)5) << std::endl;
std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(Add{}, (Values)2, (Values)5.123) << std::endl;
```

> 7
>
> 7.123

However I also want to add a `std::string` into the `Values` variant, so I can also add together strings. I am aware that it is not possible to do `string + int` for example, but I will make sure that both of `Values` is a string before attempting to run them through the visitor.

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float, std::string> Values;
std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(Add{}, (Values)"hello", (Values)"world") << std::endl;
```

However the program does not compile, giving me the error:

> Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type Add::operator ()(T,U) const'

I know that `std::string` is a object and not a type and therefore this error kind of makes sense, so I'm trying to make a special case by overloading `operator` in the `Add` struct for when the inputs are both strings:

```
auto operator() (std::string a, std::string b) const {
    return a + b;
}
```

However I get the error

> std::basic_string,std::allocator> Add::operator ()(std::string,std::string) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'T' to 'std::string'

It looks like it's still trying to run the string argument through the templated visitor.  Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do altogether? Sorry if the answer is obvious I'm still fairly new to C++, boost and templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply_visitor` should handle all combinations (even you invalid one).

You might do:

```
using Values = boost::variant<int, float, std::string>;

// Helper for overload priority
struct low_priority {};
struct high_priority : low_priority{};

struct Add : public boost::static_visitor<Values> {

    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto operator() (high_priority, T a, U b) const -> decltype(Values(a + b)) {
        return a + b;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    Values operator() (low_priority, T, U) const {
        // string + int, float + string, ...
        throw std::runtime_error("Incompatible arguments");
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    Values operator() (T a, U b) const {
        return (*this)(high_priority{}, a, b);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just trying to follow your code, how does it determine if the input is low priority or high priority?

Comment: @Tom: `high_priority` overload use SFINAE. so when both overloads are viable, *high_priority* has exact match, whereas *low_priotity* has derived to base conversion, so *high priority* wins. If high priority is discarded by SFINAE, remains only *low_priority*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Learned something new today!

Comment: priority might be replaced (when at the end of parameter list), by some integer type and C-ellipsis, but it doesn't scale well, and intend is less clear (even if generally used to create traits with SFINAE).